# Calling Table Valued Function from Visual Basic 6

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, vb6

I have some legacy code that I need to update, and I need to add a feature that uses the value returned from a table valued function. The issue I am having is that the function returns a table variable. The function is something like follows:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[SomeFunction](@intKey INT)
RETURNS @t TABLE (strValue VARCHAR(20))
BEGIN 
    (....SOME CODE.....)
    INSERT INTO @t (strValue) SELECT @SomeValue
    RETURN
END
```

The code I call the function from VB is as follows:

```
 Dim objRS As New ADODB.Recordset
 Dim objCmd As New ADODB.Command

 Set objRS = New ADODB.Recordset

 With objCmd
     .ActiveConnection = objConnection.CurrentConnection
     .CommandType = adCmdText
     .CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [dbo].[SomeFunction](?)"
     .CommandTimeout = 0
 End With

objCmd.Parameters.Append objCmd.CreateParameter("@intKey", adInteger, adParamInput)

objCmd("@intMatterID") = someObject.Key
Set objRs = objCmd.Execute

If (objRs.RecordCount > 0) Then
    someString = objRs.Fields("strValue")
End If
```

The problem seems to be that last block of code, and I have confirmed that the Recordset is not empty. The Fields value seems to always be a NULL.

So I assume that I am doing this incorrectly and was wondering if it was possible to retrieve the value of "strValue".

Comment: A Recordset does not have a Recordset property, perhaps you mean RecordCount?  I'm not sure what you're doing but wouldn't the return be a Recordset containing one row with one `adChapter` type (child Recordset) Field?

Comment: @Bob77 I am trying to get the value of strValue from the table returned from the function. This table will only ever have one row, but the values in the table vary depending on the passed in key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the issue I was experiencing was related to how I was accessing "strValue". I implemented the following and it ended up working.

```
If (objRs.RecordCount > 0) Then
    objRs.MoveFirst
    someString = Cstr(objRs("strValue"))
End If
```